# Text Classification Approach

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, text-classification

I have data with 2 important columns, Product Name and Product Category. I wanted to classify a search term into a category. The approach (in Python using Sklearn & DaskML) to create a classifier was:

1. Clean Product Name column for stopwords, numbers, etc.
2. Create 90% 10% train-test split
3. Convert text to vector using OneHotEncoder
4. Create classifier (Naive Bayes) on the training data
5. Test the classifier

I realized the OneHotEncoder (or any encoder) converts the text to numbers by creating a matrix keeping into account where and how many times a word occurs.

Q1. Do I need to convert from Word to Vectors before train-test split or after train-test split?

Q2. When I will search for new words (which may not be in the text already), how will I classify it because if I encode the search term, it will be irrelevant to the encoder used for the training data. Can anybody help me with the approach so that I can classify a search term into a category if the term doesn't exist in the training data?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Do I need to convert from Words to Vectors before train-test split?

Answer: Every algorithm takes input as some number representation of the inputs, so you have to convert from words to vectors. There is no alternative to this. Apart from OneHotEncode, there are other approaches like CountVectorizer and TfIdf-Vectorizer which are recommended to use instead of OneHotEncoding. You can read more about them [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-machine-learning-scikit-learn) .

Comment: Yes, but CountVectorizer is not relevant as most product names will be unique and will thus lead to 1 entry per row, total data is around 140Mil rows.
TF-IDF is also not required because there are no fully structured sentences, only products names from which even the stop words have been removed.
Q1 asks if the encoding is to be done before train-test split or after?

Comment: You should do encoding after train-test split.